# xlwings keyerror when running macro from excel

Tags: python, xlwings

I am following the xlwings tutorial. I downloaded and the xlwings plugin, and used the command

```
xlwings quickstart heart
```

Which created a folder with two files, heart.xlsm and heart.py. I then checked the macros in the excel file, and there is a macro with the following:

```
Sub SampleCall()
    mymodule = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, (InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))
    RunPython ("import " & mymodule & ";" & mymodule & ".main()")
End Sub
```

I think I did follow the tutorial exactly, and also made sure to install the pywin dependencies

The full error message is below:

```
---------------------------
Error
---------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Ethan-tuna\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 466, in __call__

    return Book(xl=self.xl(name_or_index))

  File "C:\Users\Ethan-tuna\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 156, in __call__

    v = self._inner(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\ETHAN-~1\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.8\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x9.py", line 41312, in __call__

    ret = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(0, LCID, 2, (13, 0), ((12, 1),),Index

pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147352565), None)



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:



Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

  File "c:\users\ethan-tuna\documents\excel plugin experiments\openpyxl test\heart\heart.py", line 6, in main

    wb = xw.Book.caller()

  File "C:\Users\Ethan-tuna\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 613, in caller

    return cls(impl=app.books[name].impl)

  File "C:\Users\Ethan-tuna\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 80, in __getitem__

    return self(key)

  File "C:\Users\Ethan-tuna\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 51, in __call__

    return self._wrap(impl=self.impl(name_or_index))

  File "C:\Users\Ethan-tuna\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 468, in __call__

    raise KeyError(name_or_index)

KeyError: 'c:\\users\\ethan-tuna\\documents\\excel plugin experiments\\openpyxl test\\heart\\heart.xlsm'



Press Ctrl+C to copy this message to the clipboard.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

As per the suggestion, I deleted the folder %localappdata%\Temp\gen_py\3.8, and then I got the following error message

```
---------------------------
Error
---------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Ethan-tuna\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 466, in __call__

    return Book(xl=self.xl(name_or_index))

  File "C:\Users\Ethan-tuna\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 156, in __call__

    v = self._inner(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\ETHAN-~1\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.8\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x9.py", line 41312, in __call__

    ret = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(0, LCID, 2, (13, 0), ((12, 1),),Index

pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147352565), None)



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:



Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

  File "c:\users\ethan-tuna\documents\excel plugin experiments\openpyxl test\heart\heart.py", line 6, in main

    wb = xw.Book.caller()

  File "C:\Users\Ethan-tuna\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 613, in caller

    return cls(impl=app.books[name].impl)

  File "C:\Users\Ethan-tuna\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 80, in __getitem__

    return self(key)

  File "C:\Users\Ethan-tuna\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 51, in __call__

    return self._wrap(impl=self.impl(name_or_index))

  File "C:\Users\Ethan-tuna\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 468, in __call__

    raise KeyError(name_or_index)

KeyError: 'c:\\users\\ethan-tuna\\documents\\excel plugin experiments\\openpyxl test\\heart\\heart.xlsm'



Press Ctrl+C to copy this message to the clipboard.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Comment: Delete this folder `%localappdata%\Temp\gen_py\3.8` and see if this solves the issue.

Comment: I deleted this folder and there is a new error message. For my understanding, why might that folder have been causing a problem?

Comment: @FelixZumstein when I delete the folder and run the program, the folder re-appears, if that is any help?

Comment: It sometimes helps: https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/1613 but I see I mixed up the error messages.

Comment: @FelixZumstein Just an observation: The KeyError shows the fullname of the Workbook (in lower case). I think it should be only the short name, passed from "--wb" parameter to Books index?

Comment: @Redoute, yes, I suspect an old version of the add-in.

Comment: thank you. it seems the problem might be that when i run install, it says it has installed the latest version, but when i run it, it says it is running v. 0.17.1